# pandas calculate mean of column that has lists instead of single value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe that has one column and it has a list of values in each row. I need to calculate the mean using the corresponding values from each row. That is I need the mean for eight values in the list. each element in the list is the value of a variable

```
>>> df_ex
0    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
1    [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1]
```

I tried converting it to numpy array and then taking the means but I keep getting an error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'`. I understand that instead of using lists, I should convert it to columns, but that in my context won't be possible. Any idea on how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can convert to nested lists first and then to `array` and then calculate the [`mean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.mean.html):

```
a = np.array(df_ex.tolist())
print (a)
[[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
 [2 3 4 5 6 7 8 1]]
 
# Mean of all values
print (a.mean())
4.5

# Specify row-wise mean
print (a.mean(axis=1))
[ 4.5  4.5]

# Specify column-wise mean
print (a.mean(axis=0))
[ 1.5  2.5  3.5  4.5  5.5  6.5  7.5  4.5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call on `np.mean` by passing nested lists and specifying an axis.

**Setup**

```
df_ex = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    col1=[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
          [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1]]))

df_ex

                       col1
0  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
1  [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1]
```

---

**Solution**

```
np.mean(df_ex['col1'].tolist(), axis=1)

array([ 4.5,  4.5])
```

Or

```
np.mean(df_ex['col1'].tolist(), axis=0)

array([ 1.5,  2.5,  3.5,  4.5,  5.5,  6.5,  7.5,  4.5])
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way:

```
col.apply(np.mean)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from ast import literal_eval  
import pandas as pd  
df=pd.read_csv("yourfile.csv", converters={"listcol": pd.eval})
def getMean(t:list[int]):  
    return sum(t)/len(t)
df["mean of listcol"]=df.apply(lambda row: getMean(row["listcol"]), axis=1)
```

#To get mean of column, where each row is a list, take np.sum(df["mean of listcol"])/ len(df)